# Как сделать нажатием кнопки перебор данных из списка поочередно

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, lambda

Хочу выводить данные из списка нажатием кнопки поочередно (по кольцу), у меня выводит все сразу!

**Update:**

А нужно по одному в одном и том же месте.

Что изменить?

```
from tkinter import *

def ok():
    list = ['Саша', 'Маша', 'Коля', 'Вася', 'Игорь']
    for i in list:
        l = Label(root, text=i).grid()

root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"150x150+500+150")
root.resizable(False, False)

b = Button(root, text='GO', command=ok)
b.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from tkinter import *


def ok(i):
    global num
    _list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#    for i in list:
    l = Label(root, text=_list[i]).grid()
    
    num += 1
    if num > 4:
        num = 0

root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"150x150+500+150")
root.resizable(False, False)

num = 0
b = Button(root, text='GO', command=lambda: ok(num))
b.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
from tkinter import *


def ok(i):
    global num
    _list = ['Саша', 'Маша', 'Коля', 'Вася', 'Игорь']
#    for i in list:

#    l = Label(root, text=_list[i]).grid()  
    l = Label(root, text=_list[i]).grid(column=1,row=2)
    
    num += 1
    if num > 4:
        num = 0

root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"150x150+500+150")
root.resizable(False, False)

num = 0
b = Button(root, text='GO', command=lambda: ok(num))
b.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но список удлиняется, а нужен перебор в одном поле, поочередно, и цифры для упрощенного примера, т.е. там будут слова

Comment: @Valentin я вас не понял - что не так? Вы пробовали запустить мой пример?

Comment: Ваш код при очередном нажатии на кнопку он перебирается правильно, но удлиняется, а нужно по одному в одном и том же месте.

Comment: @Valentin где в вашем вопросе такое написано?

Comment: @Valentin пожалуйста четко пишите в вопросе что вы хотите получить. А сейчас замените строку `l = Label(root, text=_list[i]).grid()`  на `l = Label(root, text=_list[i]).grid(column=1,row=2)`

Comment: @Valentin что не так?

Comment: Нужны не цифры, строковые данные

Comment: @Valentin я уже не рад что предложил свой вариант, но я добавил обновление в свой ответ - проверьте.

Comment: Премного благодарен! Отлично!